# Angular2: empty querystring parameters default to "true"

Tags: angular, query-string, angular-routing

Sometimes my app navigates to a route with empty parameters in the querystring, like this `cars.com/search;year=2010;model=;brand=Mazda`. But Angular is automatically updating the empty querystring parameters to 'true', changing the URL to read `cars.com/search;year=2010;model=true;brand=Mazda`. This screws up my data binding. How do I keep empty querystring parameters from defaulting to 'true'?

I'm using Angular2 rc4 and @angular/router v3.0.0-beta1.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: Please reproduce in plunker.

Comment: I've added an answer to the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39232592/6262127)